# Working with QWords

Tags: assembly, masm32

I'm learning and in the course of that working on an assembler conversion which uses QWORDs a lot (x86-32bit).  Now my reference material doesn't have anything on working with such values beyond the obvious of splitting them up into the 32-bit registers.  I guess they're on the old side.  The newer processors have mmx and sse instructions and the like. Would I be served well to look into those instructions for solving this?  What is the best way to handle doing work on QWORD values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with 64-bit integers may or may not be easy; depending on what types of operations you want to do.

For boolean arithmetic (AND, OR, XOT, NOT) it's easy to work on integers of any length just by splitting it up.

For addition and subtraction it's easy to support integers of any length by chaining together `ADC` (Add With Carry) or `SBB` (Subtract With Borrow) instructions. For example (128-bit):

```
add eax,[value]
adc ebx,[value+4]
adc ecx,[value+8]
adc edx,[value+12]  ;edx:ecx:ebx:eax = 128-bit result of addition
```

Negation is just subtraction (`-x = 0 - x`).

For shifting left/right, it's easy to support integers of any length by chaining together `SHLD` or `SHRD` instructions. For example (128-bit):

```
shld edx,ecx,12
shld ecx,ebx,12
shld ebx,eax,12
shl eax,12          ;edx:ecx:ebx:eax = 128-bit result of shift left by 12
```

If the shift count is too large (e.g. you want to shift left by 44 bits) then you need to move the data first and then shift by "original count MOD 32". For example:

```
mov edx,ecx
mov ebx,ebx
mov ebx,eax
mov eax,0          ;edx:ecx:ebx:eax = original value shifted left by 32
shld edx,ecx,12
shld ecx,ebx,12
shld ebx,eax,12
shl eax,12         ;edx:ecx:ebx:eax = original value shifted left by 44
```

For multiplication, the CPU supports "32-bit * 32-bit = 64-bit result". For anything larger you can multiply any width integer with any width integer. This is like the way you multiply large numbers by hand using base10 (where each digit is a value from 0 to 9), except you'd use base4294967296 (where each digit is a 32-bit integer). For example, to multiple 34 by 58 using base10 you'd do:

```
result_digit0to1 = 4*8 = 32
result_digit1to2a = 4*5 = 20
result_digit1to2b = 3*8 = 24
result_digit2to3 = 3*5 = 15
result = result_digit0to1 + (result_digit1to2 + result_digit1to2) * 10 + result_digit2to3 * 100;
result = 32 + (20 + 24) * 10 + 15 * 100
result = 32 + 440 + 1500
result = 1972
```

Basically, each digit in one number is multiplied by each digit in the other number while keeping track of the position/magnitude of the digits; and the result is the sum of the intermediate results.

For "64-bit * 64-bit = 128=bit result" you'd do something like:

```
result_bits0to63 = first_bits0to31 * second_bits0to31;
result_bits32to95a = first_bits32to64 * second_bits0to31;
result_bits32to95b = first_bits0to31 * second_bits32to64;
result_bits64to128 = first_bits32to64 * second_bits32to64;
result = result_bits0to63 + ( (result_bits32to95a + result_bits32to95b) << 32) + (result_bits64to128 << 64)
```

However, this only works for unsigned integers. For signed integers you need to remove the sign bit and do unsigned multiplication, then set the sign in the result afterwards (`result_sign_bit = first_sign_bit XOR second_sign_bit`).

For division, you end up doing "base2 long division". You shift the divisor as far left as you can without losing the highest set bit (while keeping track of "bits shifted"). Then you shift it back to its original position one bit at a time while comparing it with the value being divided. If the shifted divisor is smaller than the value being divided, you subtract the shifted divisor from the value being divided and set the corresponding bit in the result. After the divisor has been returned to its original position, the value being divided has become the remainder.

Like multiplication, division only really works for unsigned integers and you'd need to remove the sign bit beforehand, then do unsigned division, then set the sign (in both the result and the remainder) afterwards.

If you understand all of this; then you'd be able to (for example) do 512-bit maths with a 64-bit CPU, or 65536-bit maths with a 16-bit CPU, or "any width" maths on any CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to use instructions that work with QWORDs, unless this is explicitly forbidden by the course. Then you would have to use, as you state, 32-bits registers to do the work. You can write some subroutines to do basic logic instructions with QWORDs.

Comment: It's not for course work, but for me learning ASM (I do want the results *reasonably* fast, though), so whatever works best is what I'm wanting to know.

Comment: Then as I already said: *Best approach is to use instructions that work with QWORDs*. This is faster than doing it by 32-bits instructions.